# How to replace repetative number with '-' when it satisfy criteria from another columns

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have 5 columns(Genotype,Plants_per_plot,Plant_no.,H1,H2). I would like replace all repetitive numbers of column plant_per_plot with `-` under the condition: keep only the 1st number (i.e. the one parallel to the row `-` in the column plant_no., h1, h2)

```
Genotype Plants_per_plot Plant_no. H1 H2
184 8   -   -   -
184 8   1   12  50
184 8   2   11  48
184 8   3   11  50
184 8   4   14  52
67  7   -   -   -
67  7   1   17  61
67  7   2   20  60
67  7   3   23  59
67  7   4   22  53
98  4   -   -   -
98  4   1   21  52
98  4   2   20  56
98  4   3   18  54
98  4   4   15  52
101 9   -   -   -
```

It Should become:

```
Genotype Plants_per_plot Plant_no. H1 H2
184 8   -   -   -
184 -   1   12  50
184 -   2   11  48
184 -   3   11  50
184 -   4   14  52
67  7   -   -   -
67  -   1   17  61
67  -   2   20  60
67  -   3   23  59
67  -   4   22  53
98  4   -   -   -
98  -   1   21  52
98  -   2   20  56
98  -   3   18  54
98  -   4   15  52
101 9   -   -   -
```

Answer (score 1):

We create a logical vector with `duplicated` and assign the duplicates to '-`

```
df1[,2][duplicated(df1[1:2])] <- '-'
```

NOTE: Assuming that the 'Plants_per_plot' is `numeric` class